# Add content besides datepicker based on hoover

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Im working on a datepicker so when a user hoover over a date it shows date on top of the input bar

Here is the jfiddle im working on http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/1/

```
<div class="demo">
<h1></h1>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

But I am trying to display it content on the side of the datepicker rather than on the top.

Something like this

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL7Uv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **beforeshow**  for datepicker and call your own function.

**https://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/272/**

Please check this code with your fiddle :

```
    $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        //The calendar is recreated OnSelect for inline calendar
        onSelect: function (date, dp) {
            updateDatePickerCells();
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(month, year, dp) {
            updateDatePickerCells();
        },
        beforeShow: function(elem, dp) { //This is for non-inline datepicker
            updateDatePickerCells();
        }

    });
   updateDatePickerCells();
function updateDatePickerCells(dp) {
    /* Wait until current callstack is finished so the datepicker
       is fully rendered before attempting to modify contents */
    setTimeout(function () {

            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').after('<p>Fajr&nbsp; Sunrise&nbsp; Zuhr&nbsp; Asr&nbsp; Magrib&nbsp; Isha</p><div class="className"></div>');

    }, 0);
}

    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function() {

        $('.className').html($(this).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-month",$(this).parents()).text()+"."+$(".ui-datepicker-year",$(this).parents()).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: lol I was just doing the same thing but noticed a small bug if u change the month is disappears but if u click input box it reappears. any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry but yours doesnt show at all after u change month. Mine does http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/270/

Comment: Please check, i have updated fiddle link for new code and my post as per your MONTH change requirement  http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/272/

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the `<p>` and the `<h1>` into : `display: inline`

```
<p style="display: inline">
   Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>

<h1 style="display: inline"></h1>
```